# Error: Non Object on DOMElement

Tags: php, dom

```
foreach ($filePaths as $filePath) {
/*Open a file, run a function to write a new file 
that rewrites the information to meet design specifications */
$fileHandle = fopen($filePath, "r+");

$newHandle = new DOMDocument();
$newHandle->loadHTMLFile( $filePath );
$metaTitle = trim(retrieveTitleText($newHandle));
$pageMeta = array('metaTitle' => $metaTitle, 'pageTitle' => 'Principles of Biology' );
$attributes = retrieveBodyAttributes($filePath);

cleanfile($fileHandle, $filePath);

fclose($fileHandle);
}

function retrieveBodyAttributes($filePath) {
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($filePath);
$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
/*if (!$p->hasAttribute('body')) {
    $bodyAttr[] = array('attr'=>" ", 'value'=>" ");
    return $bodyAttr;
}*/
if ($p->hasAttributes()) {
    foreach ($p->attributes as $attr) {
        $name = $attr->nodeName;
        $value = $attr->nodeValue;
        $bodyAttr[] = array('attr'=>$name, 'value'=>$value);
    }
    return $bodyAttr;
}

}
```

$filePaths is an array of strings. When I run the code, it give me a "Call to member function hasAttributes() on non-object" error for the line that calls hasAttributes. When it's not commented out, I get the same error on the line that calls hasAttribute('body'). I tried a var_dump on $p, on the line just after the call to getElementsByTagName, and I got "object (DOMElement) [5]". Well, the number changed because I was running the code on multiple files at once, but I didn't know what the number meant. I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you loading the dom 2 times? Why not just pass `$newHandle` to the function? My guess is that if you `var_dump($dom->loadHTMLFile($filePath));` you will find `null`.

Comment: I called dom twice because I've built the code one function at a time, running each function and then integrating with the other functions and then debugging because things keep blowing up. I didn't notice this, and thank you for pointing it out. :-) 

When I var_dump on $dom->loadHTMLFile, I get boolean True on all the files. Followed by the error that I'm calling hasAttributes on a non-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with:

```
$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
```

You are executing: `DOMNodelist::item` (See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) which returns **NULL** if, at the given index, no element is found.

But you're not checking for that possibility, you're just expecting `$p` to be not null.
Try adding something like:

```
if ($p instanceof DOMNode) {
  // the hasAttributes code
}
```

Although, if you're sure that there should be a body element, you'll probably have to check your file paths.

Comment: I know that there is a body tag, but I don't know if it has attributes. What I'm trying to do is suck the onLoad and onUnload attributes out of the body code and stick them into a variable to be passed into another (included) document. If there isn't a body tag shouldn't the error message tell me which file is breaking the code?

Comment: Not necessarily, because `getElementsByTagName` allways returns a `DOMNodelist` and `DOMNodelist::item` always returns either **null** or `DOMNOde`. That's why you'll have to check for the return type. You could however try: `if (!($p instanceof DOMNode)) {/*fallback code*/}` to get files without a body tag.

Comment: Thank you, Yoshi. I think you've fixed it, but when I added the if instance of code, I wound up with about 200 mismatched tag errors, so I have to resolve those right now. Whoever coded this seemed to think that </b> and </body> are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It should be because there is no `<body>` tag in your DOM Document.

Comment: btw... turns out you were right. There's no body tag in about half the documents in this folder. ~sigh I hate fixing someone else's code. I'd rather start from scratch!

Comment: Just give me vote or mark it right :D I know sometimes, some basic things can rule everything.